# How to publish a Asp.net 5 MVC6 website on IIS containing two web apps

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have got a project with two web apps. One of them is only for reference in the base app. The project runs okay in visual studio. I am trying to publish it in local file system and then copy it across to the windows server 2008. Below is the web.config generated by visual studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="dnx-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
    <add key="dnx-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="dnx-app-base" value="..\approot\src\MySite" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I run this website in Server using `dnx . web`, it runs okay. But when I try to run it under IIS by pointing IIS to `wwwroot` then all of the packages go missing. The website is unable to find packages.

```
Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
  Base32 1.0.0.13
  BouncyCastle 1.7.0
  CsQuery 1.3.4
  EcmaScript.Net 1.0.1.0
  EntityFramework 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.Relational.Design 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta4
  EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design 7.0.0-beta4
  .........
  .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you deploy?

Here are the steps that you can follow to get that running:

1. Make sure that you the app pool is a .NET 4 app pool
2. Run, in your web app's project folder `dnu publish --runtime <name of runtime>` (the name is the name of the runtime folder under `%userprofile%\.dnx\runtimes`
3. Step 2 generates a folder that contains the application, its dependencies and the runtime under the `bin\debug` folder.
4. Copy that folder to the IIS website folder
5. Run

Comment: I am getting an exception `SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\localhost'.
` Although I am using proper connection string in Startup.cs. I am not sure why it is using AppPool as a login ?

`services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));`

Comment: Check the permissions on the app pool itself. Also, make sure the user you are trying to login as has permissions in SQL